# Load cell amplification circuit operation

Tags: operational-amplifier, load-cell

Here's the reference circuit for amplifying the signal from a load cell with precision OPAMPs as per the MAX44248 datasheet. Can this OPAMP circuitry be explained please. What's the relation between the difference of the two load cell terminals (V*cell*) and the ADC differencial input (Vin+ - Vin-)?

[image: MAX44248 load cell amplifier]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just the input stage to an instrumentation amplifier.  The voltage across \$R_g\$ is the difference in voltage between the two corners of the load cell, thus you know the current through \$R_g\$

Knowing that number, and knowing that the same current must flow throuh both \$R_F\$, you can calculate that the difference in voltages between the op amp outputs will be $$ \Delta V \left( 1 + \frac{2R_F}{R_g} \right) $$, where \$\Delta V\$ is the difference across the corners of the load cell.

The advantage is that you can change the gain by changing one resistor, \$R_g\$.  You might have to do some work to figure out what the effect of mismatched \$R_F\$ does.